# How can I understand the result Mathematica returns from DSolve?

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I have solved an ODE using `DSolve`, but I have a problem with understanding the solution.
In general the solution is in the form:

```
InverseFunction[[many expressions using # and #1]&][g x+C[1]]
```

where `g` is constant

What does `#1` and `&` mean and what does `InverseFunction` mean in this context?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Some DEs are more simple to solve for the dependent variable rather than the independent variable, for example
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = y \quad\implies\quad \log(y)=x+c $$
from which you can obtain the solution for $y$ in terms of $x$ by using an inverse function, in this case $y=\exp(x+c)$. 
Not all examples are this easy to invert, so Mathematica sometimes has to leave the solution written in terms of [`InverseFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InverseFunction.html).

The `#` and `&` are part of Mathematica's [pure (or anonymous) function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) notation. In particular `&` occurs at the end of a pure function and `#=#1` represents the first slot of the function. For example

```
(#^2 + 1&)
```

is equivalent to

```
Function[{x}, x^2 + 1]
```

and acts upon its arguments like any other function

```
(#^2 + 1&)[t] == Function[{x}, x^2 + 1][t] == t^2 + 1
```

So, your DE must have yielded a complicated algebraic expression $f(y)=x+c$ that needs to be solved for the variable that you are interested in, $y=f^{(-1)}(x+c)$, which Mathematica can only perform symbolically using `InverseFunction`.