# Ordinary differential equation invloving the function composition

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization, special-functions

I want to solve the following function:

```
DSolve[(A1*Exp[B1*f[x]] + A2*Exp[B2*f[x]])*f'[x] == A1*Exp[B1*x] + A2*Exp[B2*x], f[x], x]
```

And this is what I get as an answer:

```
{{f[x] -> InverseFunction[(A1 E^(B1 #1))/B1 + (A2 E^(B2 #1))/B2 &][(A1 E^(B1 x))/B1 + (A2 E^(B2 x))/B2 + C[1]]}}
```

Mathematica says that some results could be given in the form of the inverse functions. Does anybody know how I can solve this to get some result?

Generally the given equation involves the function composition, and has the following form:

$(g \circ f)f'=g$, where Where $g \circ f=g(f(x))$.

By inspection, $f(x)=x$ is a solution. There are also other solutions. Anybody has idea how to tackle the problem to find more solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mathematica's answer is called an implicit solution.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A simpler form the ODE shows the reason.

$$
\left(  e^{f\left(  x\right)  }+e^{bf\left(  x\right)  }\right)  f^{\prime
}\left(  x\right)  =1
$$

The solution $f\left(  x\right)$ of the differential equation is given as
a solution using inverse function. The reason is that there is no
analytical solution for $f\left(x\right)$.

```
  DSolve[{(Exp[f[x]] + Exp[b f[x]])*f'[x] == 1}, f[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The solution $f(x)$ above of the ODE is actually simple to see. It is the solution to this equation

\begin{equation}
x-e^{f\left(  x\right)  }-\frac{e^{bf\left(  x\right)  }}{b}+C=0\tag{1}%
\end{equation}

Since taking derivative of Eq. (1) the above w.r.t. $x$ gives back the ODE

\begin{align*}
1-f^{\prime}\left(  x\right)  e^{f\left(  x\right)  }-bf^{\prime}\left(
x\right)  \frac{e^{bf\left(  x\right)  }}{b}  & =0\\
\left(  e^{f\left(  x\right)  }+e^{bf\left(  x\right)  }\right)  f^{\prime
}\left(  x\right)    & =1
\end{align*}

Hence the solution of Eq. (1) for $f\left(  x\right)$ is the solution of the differential
equation. But the solution of Eq. (1) itself for $f\left(  x\right)  $ involves
inverse functions. Hence Mathematica's answer.  I  Tried

```
  SetOptions[Solve, InverseFunctions -> False];
```

To see if `DSolve` might be using `Solve` at the very end to obtain the solution of the implicit equation for $f(x)$ and this setting will make it not use `InverseFunction` but return the solution as  `Solve[.....]` which I think would have been better. but this did not work.

So the answer is: There is no actual analytical solution for $f(x)$, but an implicit solution in terms of `InverseFunction`

Some related questions and links

[accessing-reduce-from-dsolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10699/)

[how-can-i-understand-the-result-mathematica-returns-from-dsolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15978/how-can-i-understand-the-result-mathematica-returns-from-dsolve)

[problem-with-1s-in-dsolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16770/problem-with-1s-in-dsolve)

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DSolve.html