# How to get the solution from inverse function

Tags: differential-equations

When I run **Mathematica** to get the solution of a differential equation it gives the result in terms of inverse function.

```
DSolve[y'[t] == ε/Sqrt[1 + k/y[t]^2], y[t], t]
```

[image]

My question is how can we extract the actual solution from the result without the inverse function or what will be an exact solution?

Comment: Why do you think it's even possible? It looks like it's the same case as a simple `y == x + Log[x]` - there _is_ a solution for `x`, but it's not elementary; it's just `x == inverse of y`. The thing is that you'd need to solve the output for `#1` - that, given the square roots, logs etc., seems unlikely.

Comment: If you still didn't get it after corey979 comment, then probably you will get from here? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16770/problem-with-1s-in-dsolve or from here
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15978/how-can-i-understand-the-result-mathematica-returns-from-dsolve

Answer (score 2):

You can treat the InverseFunction like a normal function, plot it, build the derivative ...

```
     dsol = 
     DSolve[y'[t] == \[CurlyEpsilon]/Sqrt[1 + k/y[t]^2] && y[0] == a, y, t]

     (*   {{y -> 
          Function[{t}, 
          InverseFunction[(1/Sqrt[k + #1^2])
          Sqrt[1 + 
          k/#1^2] #1 (Sqrt[k] Log[#1] - 
          Sqrt[k] Log[k + Sqrt[k] Sqrt[k + #1^2]] + Sqrt[
          k + #1^2]) &][
          t \[CurlyEpsilon] + (1/Sqrt[a^2 + k])
          a Sqrt[(a^2 + k)/
          a^2] (Sqrt[a^2 + k] + Sqrt[k] Log[a] - 
          Sqrt[k] Log[k + Sqrt[k] Sqrt[a^2 + k]])]]}}    *)
```

Define your y

```
    y[t_, \[CurlyEpsilon]_, k_, a_] = y[t] /. First[dsol]


    Plot[Evaluate@y[t, 1/10, 2, 1], {t, 0, 100}]
```

[image]

```
    Plot[Evaluate[D[y[t, 1/10, 2, 1], t]], {t, 0, 100}]
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, the solution obtained by you is useless. It is difficult to work with. If I were you, I will use the ParametricNDSolve command, adding the parameter $a$ to $k,\epsilon$ in such a way:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{Derivative[1][y][t] == \[Epsilon]/
 Sqrt[1 + k/y[t]^2], y[0] == a},  y, {t, 0, 10}, {a, \[Epsilon], k}];
y1 = y[1, 0.1, 2] /.  sol;
y1[2] /. sol
```

> 1.11985

```
Plot[y1[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

The above plot suggests a solution which is very close to linear.

Comment: If you plot over a longer range ($0 < t < 100$, for example), you will find that the function is most assuredly not linear.  It does *look* linear over the range you've plotted, but any function will look linear if you plot it over a small enough range.

Comment: @ Michael Seifert : The numeric solution from my answer is reliable on $[0,10]$ only. The one is close to linear there.

Comment: Good point.  Still, the solutions in general will not be fully linear;  try plotting `y[0.1, 0.1, 2]` from `t = 0` to `t = 50` (after adjusting the time range).  The solutions *will* be roughly linear when the solution satisfies $y(t) \gg \sqrt{k}$, which is the regime you plotted. (Also, they'll be roughly exponential when $y(t) \ll \sqrt{k}$.)

Comment: @ Michael Seifert : The nonlinearity of the solutions is obvious. The ODE form clearly says the derivative is not constant.